# Field used like a Type

Tags: asp.net

I am getting many errors here starting with field as type! I am trying here to use a class where The user would be able to create a fashion profile by inputting details about their looks

```
public class Profile
    {
    public Profile()
    {
    }
    // method
    public string getMSG()
    {
        return "What;
    }
```

Comment: wow, you really don't have any idea how to code. It's not indented properly and paste your whole class here, rather than the subset which hardly makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I am still a beginner and don't really know how to code well. Just started learning and would appreciate a constructive comment that would be healpful to me and the others!

Comment: You could've been helpful for others and for yourself if you had just posted better and cleaner code. What I did was directed you to post the whole class rather than a subset, which is helpful for others, and you very well know why. So the comment is in every way constructive.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
```

this is wrong it should be, (remove semi colon after "if", put condition in parenthesis)

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        // your code
    }
```

also there should not be any semi colon ";" after eyeColor if you are having get/set for it.

```
    public string eyeColor
```

Comment: I removed the ; but now I am getting errors with name space cannot contain fields and properties!